# Поиск клонов по ip

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица с пользователями. Записываю в колонку iplast записываю последние входы ip. Вид примерно такой 12.12.12.12|13.14.15.16|10.12.14.15 . Нужно найти клонов, т.е. пользователей с совпадениями. Как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

Хранить IP адреса в таком виде это не лучшие практики, почитайте [ip2long](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ip2long.php)

и хранить их как строку с разделителем "|" тоже не желательно.
Создайте отдельную таблицу ip с полями user_id, ip
и записывайте туда при каждом заходе пользователя, его id и ip соответственно, так у вас будет история посещений с разных IP и правильная структура базы данных

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '12.12.12.12|13.14.15.16|12.12.12.12';
$result = array_count_values(explode('|', $str));
print_r($result);
```

выведет:

```
Array ( [12.12.12.12] => 2 [13.14.15.16] => 1 )
```

[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) - разбивает строку с помощью разделителя. В данном случае это вертикальная черта.

[array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php) - подсчитывает количество всех значений массива

Всё. Далее просто считаешь, тех, у кого значение в массиве больше 1.